# When ran an application in Genymotion i get: "Unfortunately, app has stopped."

Tags: android, appium, android-4.4-kitkat, genymotion

I'm looking for a good option to automate my tests in a mobile application. Genymotion looks the best option.

So i installed genymotion, added the arm translation and gapps in the vm, but when i try to open my application i get: "Unfortunately, [app name] has stopped."

Applications such clash of clans and facebook does works, and applications such Uber and Netflix doesnt either. This issue happens in an kit kat emulator. Jelly Bean and ICS looks fine.

Here's what logcat says:

```
01-07 16:31:04.204    2979-2979/com.psafe.powerpro I/MultiDex﹕ VM with version 1.6.0 does not have multidex support
01-07 16:31:04.204    2979-2979/com.psafe.powerpro I/MultiDex﹕ install
01-07 16:31:04.212    2979-2979/com.psafe.powerpro I/MultiDex﹕ MultiDexExtractor.load(/data/app/com.psafe.powerpro-1.apk, false)
01-07 16:31:04.212    2979-2979/com.psafe.powerpro I/MultiDex﹕ loading existing secondary dex files
01-07 16:31:04.212    2979-2979/com.psafe.powerpro I/MultiDex﹕ load found 0 secondary dex files
01-07 16:31:04.212    2979-2979/com.psafe.powerpro I/MultiDex﹕ install done
01-07 16:31:04.232    2979-2979/com.psafe.powerpro I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.content.pm.PackageManager.getPackageInstaller, referenced from method gQ.a
01-07 16:31:04.232    2979-2979/com.psafe.powerpro W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 6352: Landroid/content/pm/PackageManager;.getPackageInstaller ()Landroid/content/pm/PackageInstaller;
01-07 16:31:04.232    2979-2979/com.psafe.powerpro D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x000e
01-07 16:31:04.256    2979-2995/com.psafe.powerpro I/GMPM﹕ App measurement is starting up
01-07 16:31:04.264    2979-2979/com.psafe.powerpro D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 354K, 14% free 3003K/3464K, paused 4ms, total 5ms
01-07 16:31:04.264    2979-2995/com.psafe.powerpro E/GMPM﹕ getGoogleAppId failed with status: 10
01-07 16:31:04.268    2979-2995/com.psafe.powerpro E/GMPM﹕ Uploading is not possible. App measurement disabled
01-07 16:31:04.280    2979-2979/com.psafe.powerpro D/dalvikvm﹕ Trying to load lib /data/data/com.psafe.powerpro/files/libmobilesafe360-jni-2.7.so 0xa50565b0
01-07 16:31:04.308    2979-2979/com.psafe.powerpro A/libc﹕ Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x000000b4 (code=1), thread 2979 (.psafe.powerpro)
```

Any toughts about it?

Comment: If you did launch your app with Android studio, then you would see logs in logcat. Please copy them and past it here.

Comment: that should be your first reflex, read the logs...

Comment: I'm not very used with android logs. Is there a way to get these logs filtering by package name only? (with all log levels?)

Comment: @andrepm there is a filter on the top-right of the logcat window (might say something like "Edit Filter Configuration"). You can filter by package name there.